# angular ngIf condition inside ngFor for to display like button

Tags: node.js, angular, ngfor

I'm working with angular buttons, To implement like button depends on ngif condition inside ngFor loop and i am getting the data from two MYSQL tables posts(post_id, user_id, description), likes(like_id, user_id, post_id, like_status). I joined the two table based on user_id,and i just ngIf implement the conditions depends on user_id & post_id & like_status.

I wrote these three conditions to show the button

*ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'like'))"

*ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'unlike'))"

*ngIf="( (postLikes.length == 0) && (post.user_id != like.user_id) && (post.post_id != like.post_id) && (like.like_status != 'unlike'))"

But first two conditions working fine but the last one not working if the user_id and post_id not present in a same row , so any one please correct the ngIf condition and  help me.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  ">
  <div class="row" style=" margin: 1px; background-color: #fff; border: 2px solid #ada5a5; border-radius: 4px; ">
    <!-- ngFor for posts -->
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
      <div class="row" style="border-top: 2px solid #ada5a5;">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0" style=" height: auto; ">
          <h6> {{post.description}} </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--ngFor for likes -->
      <div class="container" style="border: 0px solid #ada5a5; ">
        <div class="row">

          <!--like button-->
          <div class=" col-4">
            <div *ngFor="let like of postLikes; let j = index ">
              <div *ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'like'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>liked</p>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="( (postLikes.length != 0) && (post.user_id == like.user_id) && (post.post_id == like.post_id) && (like.like_status == 'unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>Disliked</p>
              </div>

              <div
                *ngIf="( (postLikes.length == 0) && (post.user_id != like.user_id) && (post.post_id != like.post_id) && (like.like_status != 'unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>Default</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


  </div>
</div>
</div>

<TypeScript>

export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'my-app';
  name = 'Angular';

  posts: any[] =
    [{"post_id":4,"user_id":2,"description":" Hi How are you ","created_date":"2019-01-28T12:30:49.000Z"},{"post_id":5,"user_id":2,"description":" Working a Fine ","created_date":"2019-01-28T12:31:20.000Z"},{"post_id":6,"user_id":2,"description":" Hi How are you ......","created_date":"2019-01-28T12:32:15.000Z"},{"post_id":7,"user_id":2,"description":" 4th test post","created_date":"2019-01-29T07:10:37.000Z"},{"post_id":9,"user_id":2,"description":" 5th test post","created_date":"2019-01-31T11:17:31.000Z"},{"post_id":10,"user_id":2,"description":" 6th test post","created_date":"2019-01-31T12:03:54.000Z"},{"post_id":11,"user_id":2,"description":" 7th post post","created_date":"2019-02-08T05:50:02.000Z"},{"post_id":12,"user_id":2,"description":" 8th test post ","created_date":"2019-02-08T06:08:01.000Z"}];

  postLikes:any[] =[{"post_id":4,"user_id":2,"like_status":"unlike","like_id":10},{"post_id":5,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":9},{"post_id":6,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":8},{"post_id":7,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":7},{"post_id":9,"user_id":2,"like_status":"like","like_id":11}]

  post_id: any;
  // likes: Like[];
  like_id: number | null ;
  like_status: string;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder){


  }

  ngOnInit() {   }

  // Get user details from DB
  getPosts(user_id) {
    this.userService.getPosts(user_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.posts = data;
    },
      error => {
        return console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

// join postlikes
  getPostLikes(user_id) {
    // debugger
    this.userService.get_PostLikes(user_id).subscribe((results) => {
      this.postLikes = results;
     // console.log(results, 'results', this.postLikes, 'likes');
    },
      error => {
        return console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Once check my link for live code editing in stackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wddupe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Last two conditions are mutually exclusive, and your stackblitz does not include case where your "third" button should be visible.

Comment: If you know please correct my stackBlitz code , and the third button should be visible in default color in 6th, 7th 8th posts

Comment: Again, it requires for postLikes to be 0. And thats 5.

Comment: Can't you just create normal data model in which post has likes as propery instead of separating that to arrays for whatever reson?

Comment: i am trying to create youtube clone like dislike buttons, and there are three stages for every button, default, liked dislike , In default state there is no data in the table for the particular user_id and post_id,2nd state if he click on like button then like_status ="like", And in 3rd state if he click on dislike then like_status="unlike", And i am using only two button only there is no third button, and each button have three status, default , like, unlike.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because `*ngIf="(postLikes.length == 0) ...` will never evaluate to true inside your `<div *ngFor="let like of postLikes; let j = index ">`

If `postLikes.length == 0` then the `*ngFor` does not complete any iterations of the template.

In fact, all of the `postLikes.length` logic is actually unnecessary here.

Comment: So, `postLikes.length == 0` can use after `for` loop?

Comment: @KingStone Yep! you can check that at any time because that property is coming from your `component.ts`.

Comment: Can you please give me the suggestion to get the exact out put according to my requirement , To display the button in 6th, 7th, 8th posts if there is no user_id and post_id in a same row .